# mysql insert on duplicate key update, check which one occurred

Tags: php, mysql, unique-key, rows-affected

In PHP, how to detect which one happened (`INSERT` or `UPDATE`) in the following query:

```
INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the PHP manual [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) :

> In the case of "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" queries, the return value will be 1 if an insert was performed, or 2 for an update of an existing row.

So using the function `mysql_affected_rows()` after execution of the query, it can be detected from the returned value of the function.